# Can I add multiple images as canvas items and rotate them simultaneously?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to rotate images using canvas items. I was successful in doing it with one image. But if I want to perform rotations on multiple canvas items how can I do that? Can someone help? Thanks in advance.
Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk
from PIL import Image
import time
class SimpleApp(object):
    def __init__(self, master, filename, **kwargs):
        self.master = master
        self.filename = filename
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(master, width=500, height=500)
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.update = self.draw().__next__
        master.after(100, self.update)   
    def draw(self):
        image = Image.open(self.filename)
        angle = 0
        while (angle<90):
            tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image.rotate(angle))
            canvas_obj = self.canvas.create_image(
                250, 250, image=tkimage)
            self.master.after_idle(self.update)
            yield 
            angle += 5
            time.sleep(0.1)
        else
           yield
              
root = tk.Tk()
app = SimpleApp(root, 'cat.jpg')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you want it for multiple images on canvas or any item on canvas? also do you add the image on the same canvas or on different canvas?

Comment: Adding images as canvas items.Different canvas item for a different image.

Comment: You could do the same thing as you did in your code. What is the problem?

Comment: How do I loop the code to create such multiple canvas items

Comment: Come someone help me solve this issue, please....